# How to compute the savings at the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compute the savings from the data in the sliders and text boxes.
I am not sure where I go wrong. I want to compute the savings on click of the Button. Please correct me if I am wrong with the JS Function

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Average Kilometres per day</h1>
<input type="range" id="kms" min="5" max="80" value="5" step="1" onchange="kms(this.value)"/>
<span id="kmsValue">0</span>
<br>
<h1>Number Of Years</h1>
<input type="range" id="yrs" min="1" max="5" value="1" step="0.5" onchange="yrs(this.value)"/>
<span id="yrsValue">0</span>
</h1>
<br>
<table>
<tr>
<td><h3>Cost Of Electricity</h3><input type="text" id="elec" value="4.5"/></td>
<td><h3>Cost Of Fuel</h3><input type="text" id="fuel" value="63"/></td>
<td><h3>Fuel Efficiency</h3><input type="text" id="feff" value="45"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<button onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff)">See my savings</button>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h1>You Save :</h1></td>
<span id="savings">Savings Amount</span>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function kms(kmsValue)
{
    document.getElementById("kmsValue").innerHTML=kmsValue;
}
function yrs(yrsValue)
{
    document.getElementById("yrsValue").innerHTML=yrsValue;
}
function savings(nok,noy,e,f,fe)
{
    var nok=document.getElementById("kmsValue").value;
    var noy=document.getElementById("yrsValue").value;
    var e=(document.getElementById("elec").value)/50;
    var eff=(document.getElementById("fuel").value) / (document.getElementById("feff").value);
    var finalsavings;
    if(nok<45)
    {
        finalsavings=(kms*yrs*365);
    }
    else
    {
        finalsavings=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML=finalsavings;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon here `onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff)"` it should be `onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff);"` , infact all your events have missing semi-colon

Comment: I don get any response when I click the button :(. Is my JS function and the way I have called it is correct?

Comment: Luthando Loot , but this works ,onchange="kms(this.value)"

Comment: Rework your question title to describe your problem.

Comment: 1.Change `onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff)"` to `onClick="savings(kms,yrs,elec,fuel,feff)"` . 2. write `<span id="savings">Savings Amount</span>` inside `td`. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/0d1p6pnk/). And your calculation **may** be wrong.

Comment: I have a JS function which some some computations on the data and I want to call that function on click of a button

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your saving function with parameters which are not defined :

`<button onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff)">See my savings</button>`

The parameters **kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff** are not defined in your code and even if they were, in your function body you are creating new vars overriding them.

So just change your code to :

`function savings() {...}` and : `<button onClick="savings();">` and it should work.

[Edit] There is also the **kms** and **yrs** variables which need to be defined somewhere.
Plus I don't really understand what your are trying to do when calculating the **noy,e,f,fe** variables because you are not using them and upon reaching the end of your function execution they will be out of scope...

Comment: ok.. where exactly should I define those parameters.. you idea is not working.. can u help me with the change?

Comment: Wherever it makes sense in your workflow. If you're just reading the value then initialize them with a **getElementById**...

Comment: <button onClick="savings()">See my savings</button>
and 

function savings()
{
 var kms=document.getElementById("kmsValue").value;
 var yrs=document.getElementById("yrsValue").value;
 var coe=(document.getElementById("elec").value)/50;
 var cof=(document.getElementById("fuel").value) / (document.getElementById("feff").value);
 var finalsavings;
 if(kms<45)
 {
  finalsavings=(kms*yrs*365)*(cof-coe);
 }
 else
 {
  finalsavings=0;
 }
 document.getElementById("savings").innerHTML=finalsavings;
}

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes.

1.`onClick="savings(kms,yrs,coe,cof,eff)"`. In this line you have to give `Id's` of the elements, but you gave some other parameters like `coe,cof,eff`.
Correct Code -->`onClick="savings(kms,yrs,elec,fuel,feff)"`

2.`<span id="savings">Savings Amount</span>` must stay inside `td`.elements outside `td` are ignored.

3.To get the text inside an element other than `input` type you have to use `innerHTML`

4.`finalsavings=(kms*yrs*365);` in this line you didn't define the variables `kms` and `yrs` and you are trying is access them. 
Correct Code -->`finalsavings=(nok*noy*365);`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/0d1p6pnk/2/)

**Suggestion**: Whenever JS doesn't work JUST OPEN THE DEBUGGER > CONSOLE AND SEE THE ERRORS. Almost all debuggers give the errors that can be easily understood.

**NOTE :** one more thing there is no need of sending parameters in function while you are getting them inside the function.